# Overloading function in C++ as unsigned char and unsigned int result in ambiguous

Tags: g++, overloading

I have to overloaded functions:

```
void wypisz(unsigned int32 x, int n = 1);
void wypisz(unsigned char x, int n = 1);
```

here is code where I rise them:

```
main()
{
    wypisz((int32)(32), 7);
    wypisz('a', 7);
    return 0;
}
```

and when I try to compile it using G++ I get an error:

> test.cpp: In function '`int main()`':
>
> test.cpp:10:21: error: call of overloaded '`wypisz(int, int)`' is
>   ambiguous `wypisz((int)(32), 7);`
>
> test.cpp:10:21: note: candidates are:
>
> test.cpp:5:6: note: `void wypisz(unsigned int, int) void wypisz(unsigned int x, int n = 1);`
>
> test.cpp:6:6: note: `void wypisz(unsigned char, int) void wypisz(unsigned char x, int n = 1);`

When I remove unsigned it will compile fine.

Is there a way to call this method - wha tI should change in the call statement? Unfortunatelly I can not change anything in the declaration = they must stay as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in your function call, you are casting to an `int32`, which is neither an `unsigned char` nor an `unsigned int32`. In fact, it is implicitly castable to either of them (the compiler can convert it automatically). However, because it can convert it to *either* automatically, it doesn't know *which* to convert it to, and that is why the call is ambiguous.

To call the method unambiguously, just cast it to an `unsigned int32`:

```
wypisz((unsigned int32)32, 7);
```

Now, the compiler doesn't have to do any implicit casting, since there is an exact match. Instead, it just calls the right function.